# Rotate around alternate axis

Tags: android

I am struggling with bitmap rotations. I wish to rotate a graphic around an alternate axis but I can only ever get it to rotate around the center point no matter what I do, putting in postTranlate. preTranslate, set Translate in any order doesnt work I have also tried the postRotate(45,0,0) but it always rotates around the center.
Code below taken of internet what would I do to alter its rotation point, the code below uses the launcher icon which is square I am using a long thin graphic like an arrow.

```
// Rotate image to 45 degrees.

public void RotateImage(){
    ImageView image;
    Bitmap bMap;
    Matrix matrix;

    //Get ImageView from layout xml file
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    //Decode Image using Bitmap factory.
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    //Create object of new Matrix.
    matrix = new Matrix();

    //set image rotation value to 45 degrees in matrix.
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    //Create bitmap with new values.
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,
            bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    //put rotated image in ImageView.
    image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
}
```

I have tried the code below but its still rotates around the center or at least appears too

```
public void RotateImage{

     ImageView image;
     Bitmap bMap;
     Matrix matrix;

     //Get ImageView from layout xml file
     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     //Decode Image using Bitmap factory.
     bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

     //Create object of new Matrix.
     matrix = new Matrix();

     //set image rotation value to 45 degrees in matrix.
     matrix.setTranslate(-100,-200);
     matrix.postRotate(angle);
     matrix.postTranslate(100,200);
     //Create bitmap with new values.
     Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,
             bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

     //put rotated image in ImageView.
     image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Bitmap to rotate 45 degree around x axis with pivot (a,b), you can call `matrix.rotate(45, a, b)`

Comment: matrix does not appear to have a rotate method I guess you might mean postRotate(45,a,b) which still appears to rotate around the centre, the documentation does indicate this would work but mine always appears in the middle I guess the view could be recentering it but just cant work it out.

Comment: @user3129787 Can you provide example values which you are using? Also post some screen shots of the output for various values of a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use the Camera class to rotate around X, Y or Z axis:

```
matrix = new Matrix();

Camera camera = new Camera();
camera.save();
camera.rotateX(45f);
camera.getMatrix(matrix);
camera.restore();
```

Comment: Which `Camera` class are you referring to?

Comment: android.graphics.Camera

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP. I read the question as asking how to rotate the image around another point than the center of the image.

Comment: I agree I am not using a camera image, I am using a graphic in the drawables folder

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is that you want to rotate the image around some point, say `(x, y)`. Conceptually you need to perform the following transformations on the image:

1. Translate by `(-x, -y)`
2. Rotate by 45 degrees
3. Translate by `(x, y)`

Comment: @pskink It is the same. Is this what the documentation for `postRotate()` means? IMO, the docs are cryptic or else use mathematical notation which I am not familiar with.

Comment: I have added the below but it stays centered I dont really understand the PRE,Post,Set prefix so just guessing but it still rotates around the centre
matrix.setTranslate(-100,-200);
matrix.postRotate(angle);
matrix.postTranslate(100,200);

Comment: @user3129787 Please edit your OP with the full code for the transformation, if it still isn't working. The exact order of the calls is very crucial here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to rotate an object from center create this method in sprite class

```
public void paintFromCenter(float angle, Canvas c) {
    Bitmap b = sprite;
    Bitmap h = b;
    // Canvas canvas = new Canvas(a);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle, h.getWidth() / 2, h.getHeight());
    matrix.postTranslate(getX(), getY());
    // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());
    Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(h, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight,
            matrix, true);
    c.drawBitmap(h, matrix, null);
    // g.getCanvas().drawBitmap(bmp2, getX(), getY(), null);
}
```

Now in onTouchEvent()

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        evX = (int) event.getX();
        evY = (int) event.getY();
        int initX = objectSprite.getX();
        int inity = objectSprite.getY();

        if ((evX > objectSprite.getX()
                && evX < objectSprite.getX() + objectSprite.getWidth()
                && evY > objectSprite.getY() && evY < objectSprite.getY()
                + objectSprite.getHeight())) {
            if (angle < 90) {
                angle += 5;
            } else if (angle < -180)
                angle -= 5;

        }
}

    return true;
}
```

in draw() method paint the image/object

```
private void draw(Canvas canvas) {
objectSprite.paintFromCenter(angle, canvas);
}
```

try it